# How to alias in r gui ( windows) like we have in unix shell

Tags: r

Lets say i have a alias like this in unix

```
alias a="cd /move/to/this/directory"
```

I am looking similar alias feature in r gui ( windows 7,64-bit) to do something like this :

```
a="source('process_my_data.r')"
```

I would like to run `a` anytime I want to run `source('process_my_data.r')`

How can I avoid the need to run `source('process_my_data.r')` every time?

I am getting the below error when trying:

```
> a="source('process_my_data.r')"  
> a  
[1] "source('process_my_data.r')"  
> ./a  
Error: object '.' not found
```

Am I missing the command to execute a correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function.

```
a = function() source('process_my_data.r')
```

Then you can call `a()` at any point.

Answer (score 1):

Normally one just defines a function to easily invoke pre-written R code.  This has already been discussed in another answer to your question.

If you define such a function, `a`, then you would invoke it like this:

```
a()
```

but if you really want to just enter a variable name without the parentheses and have it execute code as shown in the question then use `makeActiveBinding` like this:

```
makeActiveBinding("a", function() source('process_my_data.r'), .GlobalEnv)
```

after which you can invoke it like this from R:

```
a
```

This works not only in Rgui on Windows but on any R platform.